# Order exporting breaks the CSV

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am trying to export the orders via `handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order` and exporting is working fine.
For example:
Exporting is working fine when someone is inserting Name as **First Name** but it brokes the CSV when someone is inserting the value like **Mr, First Name** same happening with the address section as well, Below is the code I am using.

This is what I have done so far but seems like something is missing that is why it is breaking the csv format

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_bulk_actions' );
function custom_bulk_actions( $actions ) {
    $actions['export_orders_csv'] = __( 'Export Orders to CSV', 'text_domain' );
    return $actions;
}

add_action( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_bulk_action_handler', 10, 3 );
function custom_bulk_action_handler( $redirect_to, $doaction, $post_ids ) {
    if ( $doaction !== 'export_orders_csv' ) {
        return $redirect_to;
    }

    // Export orders as CSV code goes here...

    $csv_data = ''; // Generate CSV data string
    
     // Add headings to CSV string
    $csv_data .= 'Order ID, Name, Phone Number, Address, City, Product Name, Product URL, Quanitity, Total' . "\n";

    // Get order details for each order
    foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

        // Add order data to CSV string
        $csv_data .= $order->get_id() . ',';
        $csv_data .= $order->get_billing_first_name() . ',';
        $csv_data .= $order->get_billing_phone() . ',';
        
        // Add billing address to CSV string
        $data  = $order->get_data();
        $billing_address_1  = $data['billing']['address_1'];
        $csv_data .= $billing_address_1 . ',';
        
        $csv_data .= $order->get_billing_city() . ',';
        
        
        // Add product details to CSV string
        $items = $order->get_items();
        $product_names = array();
        $product_urls = array();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product = $item->get_product();
            $product_names[] = $product->get_name();
            $product_urls[] = $product->get_permalink();
            $product_quantities['qty'] = $item->get_quantity();
        }
    
        $csv_data .= implode( ',', $product_names ) . ",";
        $csv_data .= implode( ',', $product_urls ) . ",";
        $csv_data .= implode( ',', $product_quantities ) . ",";
        $csv_data .= $order->get_total() . "\n";
    }

    // Send CSV data as download
    header( 'Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=orders.csv' );
    echo $csv_data;
    exit;
}
```

[[This is how the export file looks like after exporting]](https://cd1gz3ldda.onrocket.site/orders%20(1).csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields with commas in the string need to be quoted within a CSV file. Wrap your database fields in quotation marks.

```
$csv_data .= '"' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . '",';
```

Alternativly investigate the function `fputcsv()` which will help with this.